# Having RETURN issue in PLPGSQL

Tags: plpgsql

I have created this store procedure to return a row_version if the organization id is in the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sote.validate_row_version(a BIGINT, b BIGINT) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  ret RECORD;
  v_error_stack text;
BEGIN
  SELECT row_version INTO ret
  FROM sote.organizations
  WHERE organization_id = a;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Organization Id (%) was not found', myOrganizationID;
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_stack = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
      RETURN to_json(v_error_stack);
  RETURN '0';
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run this command,

```
SELECT sote.validate_row_version(2,4);
```

I get the following error.  I don't understand why. Any help would be great.

```
ERROR: control reached end of function without RETURN
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

- your select statement will not raise an exception unless you specify `SELECT` ... `INTO STRICT`
- your `RETURN '0'` statement is part of the exception handler and will never be executed.

So you can rewrite your function as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sote.validate_row_version(a BIGINT, b BIGINT) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  ret RECORD;
  v_error_stack text;
BEGIN
  SELECT row_version INTO STRICT ret
  FROM sote.organizations
  WHERE organization_id = a;
  RETURN '0';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Organization Id (%) was not found',   myOrganizationID;
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_stack = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
      RETURN to_json(v_error_stack);

END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and calling out STRICT to have the exception execute.  I would have been pulling my hair out on that one too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `RETURN '0'` so it's executed before the `EXCEPTION` handler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sote.validate_row_version(a BIGINT, b BIGINT) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  ret RECORD;
  v_error_stack text;
BEGIN
  SELECT row_version INTO ret
  FROM sote.organizations
  WHERE organization_id = a;

  RETURN '0';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Organization Id (%) was not found', myOrganizationID;
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_stack = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    RETURN to_json(v_error_stack);
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The code below `EXCEPTION` is all part of the exception block and won't be executed unless an exception occurs.

Best of luck.